# How to use the loop index of a for loop in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I use the index of a `for` loop in Python?

I'm trying to use `.items()`, but I did not succeed.

I know this is very basic. But I'm not getting it. I'm migrating from php to python and am encountering a few different things. Thank you

```
for index, linha in reg2.items():
        print(index, linha)
```

Error:

```
    for index, linha in reg2.items()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: `items` is used for `dicts`, you have a `list`. Given your current code, you're probably looking for [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: I intend to take the index to form an array with the result. I will edit the post for better understanding

Comment: You havent told us what data structure reg2 is

Comment: with enumerate works, but another error occurred --- data['lista'][index]['name'] = linha.name,
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: I removed the edited-in code because it seems to me it is dealing with another error entirely. It's not good to edit new questions into old posts because it can invalidate the existing answers. If you can't fix the new problem by yourself, feel free to write a new question that addresses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get your index using `enumerate()`

```
for index, item in enumerate(reg2):
    print(index, item)
```

Comment: with enumerate works, but another error occurred --- data['lista'][index]['name'] = linha.name,
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: this is because you have data['lista'][(int)]['name'].. you cannot use 'lista' or 'name' because data is a list